# Why hasn't Tony found the Defenders?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, captain-america-civil-war, defenders

Given Tony's resources, why hasn't he found the Defenders? Especially considering the fact that all four reside in New York City (the same city where Spidey lives) and three of the four have done precisely nothing to protect their secret identities.

Jessica Jones, Luke Cage, and Danny Rand should have been on Iron Man's radar for quite a while now. And considering how easily Tony tracked down Peter, figuring out Daredevil's secret identity should've been a walk in the park.

The fact that Tony went to New York to draft Spidey to his Civil War team, but ignored the four superheroes just one borough over is utterly perplexing.

The Defenders could have assisted with Captain America's capture and any other events that required superheroes.

So, Why Tony hasn't recruited them yet?

Comment: Is Tony Stark omniscient? I thought he was merely quite clever for a human

Comment: Maybe he doesn't like the idea of adding a team in? Perhaps he went for Peter because it was easier to have someone who would willingly learn from him rather than compete near the top spot?

Comment: They may have not "hidden" their identities, as such, but what have they actually 
 done *publicly* that would draw attention like Spidey does? Rand & Jones are essentially invisible and Cage had one street fight IIRC.

Comment: Spider-Man didn't do something of a very "feat" himself.

Comment: A better question is "Why recruit Spidey at all?" What does he add to the Stark side that wasn't already there? Essentially, the whole inclusion of Spidey was fan service and bringing him into the MCU rather than actually *logical*.

Comment: Not sure that Luke Cage or Jessica Jones would have taken Tony's side anyway

Comment: @Paulie_D - Isn't enough to say that having more people to fight on your side is usually better?

Comment: Peter is a kid and Stark very likely (and accurately) expected to overawe the lad with toys and charisma.  The Defenders are all more seasoned.  Each one of them, to varying degrees, butted heads with the cops  All are generally more of the lone rebel mindset.  A single glance thru their dossiers would show it all too likely they'd throw in with Cap's mindset.  Maybe...MAYBE...Daredevil as a lawyer might appreciate the need for rules and regulations, but the other three...not a chance.

Answer (score -2):

Out of universe reason

Because like the Deadpool and Xmen movies the TV series "The defenders" is not part of the MCU Marvel comics universe Earth-199999 they may be in the future but as of currently now they are not.

In universe reason

Tony stark and most of the other avengers possibly don't know of The defenders yet, because quite unlike the comic books and Cartoon series, the MCU multiverse Earth-199999 is quite young and the avengers that exist in Earth-199999 are not very informed of other Hero's, Villians and other people who they know in the comics because Earth-199999  is so quite young.

Comment: But isn't it already confirmed that they are part of the same universe?